# Handling both specific and general Python exceptions?

Tags: python

I would like to catch a specific exception and handle it accordingly - then I would like to continue and perform the generic handling that other exceptions would have to.

Coming from a C background, I could have previously utilised gotos to achieve the desired effect.

This is what I'm currently doing is and it works fine:

```
try:
    output_var = some_magical_function()
except IntegrityError as ie:
    integrity_error_handling()
    shared_exception_handling_function(zde) # could be error reporting
except SomeOtherException as soe:
    shared_exception_handling_function(soe) # the same function as above
```

## Tldr:

Ie - is there "Pythonic" way of doing the following:

```
try:
    output_var = some_magical_function()
except IntegrityError as ie:
    integrity_error_handling()
except ALLExceptions as ae: # all exceptions INCLUDING the IntregityError
    shared_exception_handling_function(ae) # could be error reporting
```

NB: I am aware of the finally clause - this isn't intended for tidy-up (ie- closing files)·

Comment: Unfortunately in Python there's no `case switch`-alike techniques to "fall through" certain exceptions but to construct a cascaded `try..except` structure to handle specific in inner, then raise to outer for general handling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could *reraise* the exception, and handle the generic case in the outer handler of a nested setup:

```
try:
    try:
        output_var = some_magical_function()
    except IntegrityError as zde:
        integrity_error_handling()
        raise
except ALLExceptions as ae: # all exceptions INCLUDING the IntregityError
    shared_exception_handling_function(ae) # could be error reporting
```

The unqualified `raise` statement re-raises the current exception, so the `IntegrityError` exception is thrown again to be handled by the `AllExceptions` handler.

The other path you could take is to test for the exception type:

```
try:
    output_var = some_magical_function()
except ALLExceptions as ae: # all exceptions INCLUDING the IntregityError
    if isinstance(ae, IntegrityError):
        integrity_error_handling()
    shared_exception_handling_function(ae) # could be error reporting
```

Comment: The second approach would be appropriate for certain libraries with a pool of specific errors that inherits the same parent exception. The first is more suitable when generalization is harder to make. Combining both is near-bullet-proof yet still elegant/Pythonic, imho.

Comment: @woozyking: But for `ALLExceptions` to catch `IntegrityError`, it *has* to be a base class for the latter.

Comment: Indeed. I assume a lot of people would start with creating subclasses to the generic `Exception` and then work on mid-level abstraction when needed.

Comment: Should we modify our questions & answers to remove any ambiguity (ALLExceptions -> Exceptions)? It'll be one less question for newcomers when they're reading up on the thread...

Comment: I don't think so; and generally speaking, it is a bad idea to use `except Exception:` or `except:` as you'll be catching keyboard interrupts, memory errors and such as well.

Answer (score 6):

The `Exception` class will match all exceptions...

```
try:
    output_var = some_magical_function()
except IntegrityError as zde:
    integrity_error_handling()
except Exception as ae:
    shared_exception_handling_function(ae) # could be error reporting
```

But it sounds like you want the final clause to run for both `IntegrityError` exceptions as well as everything else.  So you'll need a different construct, possibly this:

```
try:
    try:
        output_var = some_magical_function()
    except IntegrityError as zde:
        integrity_error_handling()
        raise
except Exception as ae:
    shared_exception_handling_function(ae) # could be error reporting
```

The `raise` command on the inner `try`...`except` block causes the
caught exception to be passed up to the outer block.

Comment: `Exception` matches all built-in exceptions that do not lead to system exit.